# react-native ios custom ui component is not displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE0Zt.png)

When I run this project in Xcode, 'NSLog(@"view init......")' this line has been executed, but the React component is not displayed in iOS simulator. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resolved this problem. I missed the style of this component and also make sure the Width & Height had been set.

Answer (score 0):

Also setting *flex: 1* to the style of the component should do the trick.